# Setting the Location of UIBezierPath Object

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I want to create a semi-circle arch. I have achieved that using UIBezierPath. However, my issue is that the location of my arch is not where I want it to be.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, I want the blue object to be centred, but it is leaning to the left. Code below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var logo_backdrop: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Setting Login View Background
    let bgColor = UIColor(red: 128, green: 206, blue: 201)
    self.view.backgroundColor = bgColor

    //Setting Logo Backdrop color
    let backdrop = UIColor(red:183, green:227, blue:239)
    logo_backdrop.backgroundColor = backdrop

    //Setting Round Corner for Logo Backdrop
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: logo_backdrop.bounds,
        byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
        cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    maskPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.width, y: 0.0))

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.frame = logo_backdrop.bounds
    shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
    logo_backdrop.layer.mask = shape
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is that your code is in `viewDidLoad`. That is *too soon*, as the various views have not yet taken on their real size. But your code depends upon that size, so it must not be run too early.

For example, your bezier path depends upon `logo_backdrop.bounds`, but those bounds are exactly what we do not know in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: The obvious place is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But be careful, because that method is called many times, and you only want to do this stuff the _first_ time.

Comment: when is the viewDidLayoutSubviews called again? Given your suggestion then, what is better way of doing this?

Comment: What I do is use a Bool property so that I run the configuration code only once.